# Edit the USB mass storage driver

Tags: drivers, usb-drive, mass-storage

I want to edit the USB MSD, to show a message whenever i plug a device (like a flash drive) to my computer. How do i do it? Which file exactly is to be edited and how?

Comment: You need to see this:[How to get an email notification when a USB storage device is inserted?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/192331/how-to-get-an-email-notification-when-a-usb-storage-device-is-inserted) and this [How do I make udev rules work?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/297412/how-do-i-make-udev-rules-work)

Comment: [UsbDriveDoSomethingHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsbDriveDoSomethingHowto)

Comment: Did you ever try my solution below?

Comment: yes i did! But what i wanna know is, editing the code of class driver of a particular device, so that when it is attached to the system, the console should show a message. That's what my manager has told me to do.

Comment: I read somewhere that i can use /linux/drivers/usb/storage
But i exactly dont know.

Answer (score 1):

The driver has nothing to do with this, it just manages the device and allows the kernel to communicate with it. What you want is a much higher lever function.

The way to do this is using [`udev`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev), the device manager for the Linux kernel:

1. Create a script that will send the notifications. Save the following lines in a file in your home directory, for example `~/usbnotify.sh`:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   export DISPLAY=":0"
   notify-send "New device plugged in: $@"
   ```

   Make the script executable by running `chmod +x ~/usbnotify.sh`
2. Create a new file called `/etc/udev/rules.d/95-usbnotify.rules` with the following contents (adapted from [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=818799#p818799)):

   ```
   KERNEL!="sd[a-z]*", GOTO="media_by_label_auto_mount_end"
   ACTION=="add", PROGRAM!="/sbin/blkid %N", GOTO="media_by_label_auto_mount_end"

   # Get label
   PROGRAM=="/sbin/blkid -o value -s LABEL %N", ENV{dir_name}="%c"
   # use basename to correctly handle labels such as ../mnt/foo
   PROGRAM=="/usr/bin/basename '%E{dir_name}'", ENV{dir_name}="%c"
   ENV{dir_name}=="", ENV{dir_name}="usbhd-%k"

   ACTION=="add", ENV{dir_name}!="", RUN+="/home/akshay/usbnotify.sh %c", GOTO="media_by_label_auto_mount_end"

   # Exit
   LABEL="media_by_label_auto_mount_end"
   ```

   Make sure to use the correct path to the script, I used `/home/akshay/usbnotify.sh` but edit to point to your home directory.

Save the script and that's it. You should now receive a notification for every device that you plug in that is mounted as a drive. This will probably not work for cameras and the like but any storage device that is attached as `/dev/sd*` should work.